# How to count the number of rows that have data in a pipe-delimited file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a file like this

```
1|2345|John|Smith
2|4563||Smith
3|5968||Doe
4|896|Rick|Lawson
5|889||Eddy
```

How do I count the number of rows that have data in the third column?

Comment: `grep -Pc '^(?:[^|]*[|]){2}[^|]'` should also get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' 'length($3) { ++count } END { print count }' < input
```

On the sample input, it results in:

```
2
```

It works by setting the field separator to pipe, then increments `count` on lines that have a non-empty value in the 3rd field. At the end of the file, it prints the final `count`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question. How do I print the third row that has data?

Comment: The 3rd row? It doesn't have data in the 3rd field. Did you mean "how to print rows that have data in the 3rd column"?  Then just amend the `++count` to `++count; print`

Comment: @Bala.C To print _the third row that has data_, use Jeff's code with a tiny modification: `awk -F '|' 'length($3) { ++count } length($3) && count==3' <input`

Answer (score 3):

Using software tools:

```
cut -d '|' -f 3 input | wc -w
```

This assumes column 3 is only one word, with no spaces.  If there might be spaces, this should work:

```
cut -d '|' -f 3 data | grep -c .
```